# error while writing Map: /wordcount$Map.class (Permission denied)

Tags: hadoop, dictionary

I'm trying to run wordcount example on my hadoop 2.7.1, but i get this error msg after compiling wordcount.java file.
I've placed .java file in the Desktop only

[image]

Comment: Please add error messages as text in a code block. Further, there are two errors, first solve the error where the compiler complains about missing write permissions on the target file: check the path and it's permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Give the Read and Write Permission to WordCount Directory and try.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
You may get this problem in 2 cases :
```

1) `Compiling the filename.java file as a non administrator` ( meaning that you are compiling the file while being in sudo mode or as other user like hduser in hadoop ) .

> To get rid of this , change the user mode to your user or current user

.

2) `Permissions are not available for the compiler to write in to the place where the filename.java is available` .

> enable the permission in the properties and try again

.